# How to write right regular expression for my Route path in React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have some troubles with writing regular expressions in my React JS application.
Suppose that my  have to check only paths like "/articles/page-2" or "/articles/page-1" or just "/articles/". What is the right way for doing it correctly?

```
<Route path={'/articles/(page-)?:pageNumber?'}/>
```

I've tried following path, but it's not the right path. This route would render it even when URL is "/articles/-3"

Answer (score 1):

For capturing only `pageNumber` is better to break into 2 routes. Create the first for capturing `/articles` only and the second with the desired pattern.

you can write as `page-:pageNumber(\d)`, where `\d` means digit. you must also include `exact={true}`, to ensure an exact match for your path. With that you can use [useParams](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams) later to extract `pageNumber`:

```
<Route path={'/articles'} exact={true} />
<Route path={'/articles/page-:pageNumber(\d)'} exact={true} />
```

Comment: It works, but point is that I need to store somewhere page number, I can do it by adding 
":pagenumber", but I don't know how to write right regex to track path like "page-2" or "page-3"

Comment: I updated my answer given your needs. I don't think that result is achievable with one `Route` only. it's better to break into 2 routes which is easier to maintain overall.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood, and also not sure if you can do that.. but try

```
<Route path={`/articles/${pageNumber ? "page-" + pageNumber : ''}`}/>
```

Comment: I can't do that, because pageNumber is not a JS variable, it's URL parameter in React Router DOM